# Почему не подключается к базе данных?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Отключил брандмауэр. Пишет, что подключение не установлено, т. к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос 127.0.0.1

```
MySqlDataReader mysqldatareaderstrah; // или MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader mysqldatareaderstrah;
dataGridView1.Refresh();
// проверка наличия запроса
if (textBox1.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Введите или выберите запрос!", "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    return;
}
try
{
    string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=True";
    MySqlConnection connect = new
    MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    connect.Open();
    MySqlCommand mysqlcommand = new MySqlCommand(textBox1.Text, connect);
    mysqldatareaderstrah = mysqlcommand.ExecuteReader();
    // массив для записи даннЫх
    ArrayList arraylist = new ArrayList(0);
    foreach (DbDataRecord record in mysqldatareaderstrah)
    {
        arraylist.Add(record); // запись результатов запроса
    }
    // закрытие соединения        
    mysqldatareaderstrah.Close();
    // перенос результатов в таблицу вывода
    dataGridView1.DataSource = arraylist;
```

Строка подключения взята отсюда

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот ошибка:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005)
Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. -->
System.AggregateException: Произошла одна или несколько ошибок. -->
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Подключение не установлено,
т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение 127.0.0.1:3306
```

Comment: Определитесь, с чем именно вы работаете: MySql или Sql Server. Используйте соответствующую метку. Ошибку вставьте текстом, а не скриншотом.

Comment: Вы типичный "уверенный пользователь ПК"? Не в курсе, что текст с MessageBox'а копируется нажатием Ctrl+C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых, Вы взяли строку подключения из примера, предназначенного для MS SQL Server, а подключаться пытаетесь к MySQL.

Плохо в этом то, что у Всс просто неправильная connection string. Это видно уже по тому, что в ней присутствует параметр `Integrated Security=True` - он имеет смысл только для MS SQL Server.

В [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-string.html) пишут, что строка коннекта должна выглядеть примерно так: `server=127.0.0.1;uid=konst;pwd=your-super-secret-password;database=test`

Во вторых, в MySQL "по умолчанию" для многих пользователей подключение "снаружи" не разрешено. Его нужно разрешать отдельно.

Если память мне не изменяет, делается это примерно так:

```
    CREATE USER 'konst'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-super-secret-password';

    grant all privileges on *.* to 'konst'@'127.0.0.1';

    ALTER USER 'konst'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your-super-secret-password';
```